# form.valid always true with custom field component

Tags: angular, forms

I'm using Angular 6. I created a custom component called QuestionComponent to provide dynamic inputs, checkboxes, radio buttons and textareas on a form (template-driven one). So it can be used like this:

```
My model:
export class Question {
   code: number;
   type: string;
   description: string;
   answer?: string;   
}
```

App.component:

```
<form name="f" #f="ngForm" role="form">
    <div *ngFor="let question of model.questions">
        <question [required]="true" [question]="question"></question>
    </div>
    ...
</form>
```

It will create an field like this, for example:

```
<label>{{ question.description }}</label>
<textarea name="question.code" required id="question.code" [(ngModel)]="question.answer"></textarea>
```

It is working as expected, but my f.form.valid is always "true", even with the "required" tag.

How can I validate my form with these custom "question" component?

Comment: Hey, I'm wondering why you aren't using Reactive Forms instead of TD, especially when working with dynamic controls ?

Comment: because I am not familiar with reactive form

Comment: Well, I agree it looks a little bit hard to learn, but believe me if you learned its basics and used it once, you will begin wondering why would you use TD forms while Angular has built that great option., give it a shot and you won't regret it.
https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms